# Unable to install Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, spring-tool-suite, ggts

Am trying to install Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) for Eclipse into my Eclipse installation.

version of Eclipse installed:
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) - Windows 32-bit.

When I attempt to install ggts from the eclipse marketplace either by using the Eclipse Marketplace
menu option or by using the ggts drag to install button, the following window/error message is 
obtained after selecting Confirm:

The following solutions are not available  Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) for Eclipse 3.6.4.RELEASE,
Proceed with the installation anyways?

How/can it be installed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to put in the right (and versioned) update site into the Marketplace entry definition after the 3.7.0 release went out. This is fixed now. You should be able to install GGTS from the Marketplace again. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for pointing me at this here.

Keep in mind that there is no new GGTS version that is compatible with Eclipse Mars. The last version is 3.6.4 and is compatible with Eclipse 4.4 and previous versions.